Disks are not showing up in the setup page
I'm trying to install Ubuntu but the disks are not showing up in the setup page see for your self in the picture.  I would appreciate your help

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop

I'm sorry my bad https://ibb.co/5M9W3PY and it us ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop
